# How do I get the Browser languages from a page that is in an iframe?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe, facebook-iframe

I can use Request.UserLanguages to get the Browser languages within a page, however if that page is then within an iFrame, it seems there is no languages? how do I get this information from the parent iFrame?

This iframe is in fact a Facebook iFrame app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only be able to query info about the page if it is on the same domain and page calling the i-frame, due to cross domain security.

> "The fact that the i-frame is controlled by Facebook you will not be 
>   able to XSS."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

if you control the i-frame, and it is php you can expose the document "at your own risk" 
add this snippet to the top of your php document before all other code.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

then you can proceed to get information with JavaScript as you normally would.

Comment: Thanks, its looks like I can detect the language/locale via the facebook api, will try that route..

Comment: sure thing, if you would post your solution for the api, so other users with similar issue can find.